# Seeing an Issue With Live Apps Developer Set Up on Mac Pro

Tags: quip

I'm going through the [Live Apps Hello World][1] page, and I'm seeing some odd behavior for which there is no info on Stack exchange. Things are building okay, but the app doesn't update with changes to sources when npm is running. I'm on a mac pro trying to put this together.

I'm running node v12.10.0 and npm 6.11.3 (these were the ones installed by default with brew).

The first time I built and ran Hello World, it worked. But when I followed the instructions under **Develop Your App**, changes wouldn't show. Clicking reload crashes the npm server.

I tried redoing with a second app, doing 'sudo' this time, and no joy.

Finally, I tried with an app from scratch, but not building until I'd created the Sticky Note app (later on the same page). The Sticky Note app never worked.

Here's an typical log from when the server is shut down:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok

1 verbose cli [

1 verbose cli '/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.10.0/bin/node',

1 verbose cli '/usr/local/bin/npm',

1 verbose cli 'start'

1 verbose cli ]

2 info using npm@6.11.3

3 info using node@v12.10.0

4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]

5 info lifecycle secondTry@0.0.1~prestart: secondTry@0.0.1

6 info lifecycle secondTry@0.0.1~start: secondTry@0.0.1

7 verbose lifecycle secondTry@0.0.1~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true

8 verbose lifecycle secondTry@0.0.1~start: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/nod\

e_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/fribble-boo/dev/quip-live-apps/secon\

dTry/node_modules/.bin:/Users/fribble-boo/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/\

sfdc-zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/User\

s/fribble-boo/.ansible

9 verbose lifecycle secondTry@0.0.1~start: CWD: /Users/fribble-boo/dev/quip-live\

-apps/secondTry

10 silly lifecycle secondTry@0.0.1~start: Args: [ '-c', 'NODE_ENV=development webpac\

k-dev-server --https' ]

11 silly lifecycle secondTry@0.0.1~start: Returned: code: 1 signal: null

12 info lifecycle secondTry@0.0.1~start: Failed to exec start script

13 verbose stack Error: secondTry@0.0.1 start: `NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-ser\

ver --https`

13 verbose stack Exit status 1

13 verbose stack  at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/no\

de_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)

13 verbose stack  at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:209:13)

13 verbose stack  at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/no\

de_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)

13 verbose stack  at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:209:13)

13 verbose stack  at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)

13 verbose stack  at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.\

js:283:5)

14 verbose pkgid secondTry@0.0.1

15 verbose cwd /Users/fribble-boo/dev/quip-live-apps/secondTry

16 verbose Darwin 18.7.0

17 verbose argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.10.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "star\

t"

18 verbose node v12.10.0

19 verbose npm v6.11.3

20 error code ELIFECYCLE

21 error errno 1

22 error secondTry@0.0.1 start: `NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --https`

22 error Exit status 1

23 error Failed at the secondTry@0.0.1 start script.

23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging\

 output above.

24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]


  [1]: https://salesforce.quip.com/dev/liveapps/
```

Comment: More info. When I try co use local resources, the Chrome console displays:

GET https://localhost:8888/dist/app.css net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
2view-frame:2 GET https://localhost:8888/dist/app.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

But I have enabled the chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost property. Shouldn't it just work?

Comment: I am seeing this same issue and not finding resources to solve. @antorcol have you been able to resolve?